# How to Use Css Variable in React Component?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I want to use content variable with in-line styles in react, but I dont know how to do this ?

CSS3

```
.right::after, button::after {
 
  content: var(--content);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 40px 40px;
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

React Component

```
 return (
    <Button
      {...configButton}
      style={{'--content': "Login" }}
    >
        <div class="left"></div>
             Login
    <div class="right"></div>
      {children}
    </Button>
  );
```

Comment: Can you post the code of your `<Button>` component, or if it's from a package, show us which package it is from?

Comment: What version on MUI you are using? If it is MUI v5 i would suggest to use the `sx` property or even better to use styled components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the solution to this problem is quite simple, It made me think for a while.

The css variable that you provided works indeed.

But when it comes to the content of a psudo element then you should provide the value with a pair of quotes and it will work fine.

```
<Button
      {...configButton}
      style={{'--content': "'Login'" }}
    >
```

change the `"Login"` into `"'Login'"` and this should work fine.
thank you.

Answer (score -1):

It should work.
Are you passing `style` to the actual rendered element in `Button` component?
Is the CSS aplied?

```css
div:after {
  content: var(--test-var);
}
```

```html
<div style="--test-var: 'Test'"></div>
```

Comment: But how tu use in react inline styles? Because in react inline styles should be like this style={{height:10}}

Comment: The way you did it is correct, `style={{ '--content': 'test' }}` should work. The problem is probably that your `<Button>` component doesn't pass the styles to the actual button, or to a different (possibly wrapper or child) element instead